# Memória reservada para o tomcat

Tags: java, servidor, tomcat, lado-do-servidor

Meu sistema está em um servidor que tem vários tomcats, necessito desativar o tomcat que mais tem memória reservada para ele.

Como vejo a memória reservada para cada tomcat no servidor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Heap de memória usado pelo tomcat é definido pelo parâmetro **jvm -Xmx**.

Verifique se existe a variável de ambiente

```
CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms64m -Xmx256m
```

Verifique se a variável acima é usado pelo script abaixo:
Além disso verifique o parâmetro **JAVA_OPTS** -Xmx1024m nos scripts abaixo

```
tomcat-install/bin/catalina.sh(.bat) 
tomcat-install/bin/startup.sh(.bat)
```

Um modo mais simples é simplesmente executar o comando, porém somente em linux

```
ps -ef | grep java
```

e procurar pela instância do tomcat verificando os parâmetros **Xms** e **Xmx**

Comment: Esse comando ps -ef | grep java  eu posso rodar no CMD do servidor?

Comment: Sim desde que seja linux

Comment: Infelizmente é windows, a empresa deixou instalar nessa benção.

Comment: Editei a resposta, como é windows você precisa olhar os arquivos .bat da instalação para ver a memória alocada para o server